# Spring Boot doesn't pick up Micrometer Registry from the classpath (cloudwatch)

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I use Spring Boot 1.5 with micrometer-spring-legacy:1.1.4 and micrometer-registry-cloudwatch:1.1.4 on the classpath. According to the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/1.5#_configuring) it should pick up this registry automatically:

> Having a dependency on micrometer-registry-{system} in your runtime classpath is enough for Spring Boot to configure the registry.

However when I look at the registered Spring beans when the app starts, there is only "simpleMeterRegistry" (which I assume is the default).

Why does it not pick up the `CloudWatchMeterRegistry`? How to troubleshoot? thank you!!!

From the log:

> Condition CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration.MultipleNonPrimaryMeterRegistriesCondition on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration did not match due to NoneNestedConditions 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration.MultipleNonPrimaryMeterRegistriesCondition.SingleInjectableMeterRegistry @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'simpleMeterRegistry'; NestedCondition on CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration.MultipleNonPrimaryMeterRegistriesCondition.NoMeterRegistryCondition @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'simpleMeterRegistry'
>
> Condition DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.DataSourcePoolMetricsConditionalOnBeans on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration matched due to AllNestedConditions 2 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.DataSourcePoolMetricsConditionalOnBeans.ConditionalOnMeterRegistryBean @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'simpleMeterRegistry'; NestedCondition on DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.DataSourcePoolMetricsConditionalOnBeans.ConditionalOnDataSourceBean @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource'
>
> Filter 'webMetricsFilter' configured successfully

### Update

I see there is `CloudWatchMetricAutoConfiguration` and I would expect it to produce a `CloudWatchMetricWriter` Bean but there is no such bean. It should also create a `AmazonCloudWatchAsync` bean but it doesn't - the only "*amazon*" bean we have is `amazonS3`.

### Likely cause

I have discovered that `micrometer-spring-legacy:1.1.4` has the package `io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.export.<system>` with `<system>MetricsExportAutoConfiguration`, `<system>Properties`, `<system>PropertiesConfigAdapter` for every supported system - but not CloudWatch. These classes make the *Registry available as a Spring bean and since there is no support for the cloudwatch registry, it is not available as a spring bean.

Comment: In Spring Boot 2 this happens when you don't include Actuator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484479/625581.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I lacked micrometer-spring integration for CloudWatch, which is not included in micrometer-spring-legacy because of its dependencies. Instead, it lives in the Spring Cloud AWS repo, namely [in the package `org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.metrics`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/tree/master/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/metrics) of the [`spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure/2.0.0.RELEASE/jar) library.

See [spring-projects/spring-boot#11276](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/11276) for background.

However spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure 2 expects Boot 2.x, the latest made for Boot 1.5 is 1.2.3 which lacks the CloudWatch metrics integration. The only option is thus to copy, paste, adjust its `CloudWatchMetricsExportAutoConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was that I was using `micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2`, which wasn't compatible with my SpringBoot. So I used `micrometer-registry-cloudwatch` and everything worked.